# Django nested prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I'm using nested prefetching to link all my objects with each other and then pushing them to a template to show them.

My general setup: I have frameworks, categories and controls. A control is linked to a category, a category is linked to a framework. A category can also have a supercategory, in which case the category has a call to another category object. Every control also has an initial score, current score and a target score.

What I want to do is for every framework, for every supercategory, for every subcategory show every control with their scores.

Example:

```
Framework A
  Super Category 1
    Subcategory 1
      Control 1
        Initial
        Current
        Target
      Control 2
       ...
    Subcategory 2
      Control 3
       ...
  Super Category 2
     Subcategory 3
       Control 4
        ...

Framework B
...
```

I've already managed to do this by using a lot of nested prefetches.

My models:

```
# models.py
#==============[FRAMEWORKS]==============#
class Framework(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.replace(' ', '_')

class FrameworkCat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              verbose_name="optional identifier")
    framework = models.ForeignKey(Framework,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              verbose_name="related framework")
    superCat = models.ForeignKey('self',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             verbose_name="super category",
                             blank=True,
                             null=True)

    hexColor = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            verbose_name="hex color")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#==============[CONTROLS]==============#
class Control(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    framework = models.ForeignKey(Framework,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name="related framework")
    category = models.ForeignKey(FrameworkCat,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             verbose_name="related category",
                             null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProjectScore(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            verbose_name="related project")
    control = models.OneToOneField(Control,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            verbose_name="related control")
    framework = models.ForeignKey(Framework,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              verbose_name="related framework")

    score = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    current_score = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    target = models.IntegerField(default=-1)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Project Score"
```

My (testing) view:

```
# views.py
def testing_models(request):
    def_data = default_data(request)


    frameworks = Framework.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('frameworkcat_set',
                                                         queryset=FrameworkCat.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('frameworkcat_set',
                                                         queryset=FrameworkCat.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('control_set',
                                                         queryset=Control.objects.select_related('projectscore').order_by('id'),
                                                         to_attr='controls')).exclude(superCat=None),
                                                         to_attr='categories')).filter(superCat=None),
                                                         to_attr='supercategories')).all()

    def_data['frameworks'] = frameworks

    return render(request, 'testing_models.html', def_data)
```

And my template to show everything:

```
# templates/testing_models.html
{% for framework in frameworks %}
    {% for supercategory in framework.supercategories %}
        <p><strong>{{ supercategory.name }}</strong></p>

        {% for subcategory in supercategory.categories %}
            <p>{{ subcategory.name }}</p>

            {% for control in subcategory.controls %}
                <p>{{ control.title }}</p>

                <p>{{ control.projectscore.score }}</p>
                <p>{{ control.projectscore.current_score }}</p>
                <p>{{ control.projectscore.target }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This all works correctly by executing 6 queries. Now, my main question is: is there a better way to fetch these objects and link them than using all these nested prefetches? Is there some other kind of syntax that I could be using that makes it easier to read and easier to modify? I have many more things I would like to link but I'm afraid the python statement would become too big and my overview would be lost.

Much appreciated!

Comment: I think you can just use a standard join query using prefetch_related, and then achieve the ordering in your template via the regroup tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Also you might want to look at related_name to make referencing the various models from your Framework model easier. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: BTW, you need to sort on columns you want to use regroup on in your (view) query. For some reason the django documentation does not mention this.

Comment: @DisneylandSC Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I'm looking for maybe a simpeler notation than the one I'm using right now. I read about things like prefetch_related('a__b__c') for nested prefetches but I have no clue how to apply them here.